# Are there any NuPIC precompiled images available?

Tags: linux, installation, nupic, hierarchical-temporal-memory

Are there a precompiled binaries, images or installers for [NuPIC](http://numenta.org/nupic.html)?

Alternatively, are there any ISO images of Ubuntu with NuPIC baked in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an Ubuntu Virtual Box image at https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B99vQZHZRc_gY0VhOFdPNGo5Rlk/view?usp=sharing (it's 6Gb).

Also, see https://github.com/numenta/nupic/wiki/Running-NuPIC-in-a-Virtual-Machine

Comment: Thanks, Matthew. For anyone using this image, the password is the same as the default username.

Comment: @MatthewTaylor You should update this answer, given that the Wiki for NuPIC doesn't exist anymore.